# Google cloud click to deploy hadoop

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-hadoop

Why does google cloud click to deploy hadoop workflow requires picking size for local persistent disk even if you plan to use the hadoop connector for cloud storage? The default size is 500 GB .. I was thinking if it does need some disk it should be much smaller in size. Is there a recommended persistent disk size when using cloud storage connector with hadoop in google cloud?

"Deploying Apache Hadoop on Google Cloud Platform

The Apache Hadoop framework supports distributed processing of large data sets across a clusters of computers.

Hadoop will be deployed in a single cluster. The default deployment creates 1 master VM instance and 2 worker VMs, each having 4 vCPUs, 15 GB of memory, and a 500-GB disk. A temporary deployment-coordinator VM instance is created to manage cluster setup.

The Hadoop cluster uses a Cloud Storage bucket as its default file system, accessed through Google Cloud Storage Connector. Visit Cloud Storage browser to find or create a bucket that you can use in your Hadoop deployment.

Apache Hadoop on Google Compute Engine
Click to Deploy Apache Hadoop
Apache Hadoop
ZONE 
us-central1-a 
WORKER NODE COUNT

CLOUD STORAGE BUCKET 
Select a bucket 
HADOOP VERSION
1.2.1 
MASTER NODE DISK TYPE
Standard Persistent Disk 
MASTER NODE DISK SIZE (GB)

WORKER NODE DISK TYPE 
Standard Persistent Disk 
WORKER NODE DISK SIZE (GB) 
"

Comment: Where does it say anything about local disk?

Comment: May be local is not the right word .. I was referring to the " "Standard Persistent Disk" size requirement for both master and worker nodes.

Comment: I would imagine the disk of this size is "required" for worker MR jobs, the cloud storage is probably used for the output of the job? I'm only guessing here, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The three big uses of persistent disks (PDs) are:

- Logs, both daemon and job (or container in YARN)

  - These can get quite large with debug logging turned on and can result in many writes per second
- MapReduce shuffle

  - These can be large, but benefit more from higher IOPS and throughput
- HDFS (image and data)

Due to the layout of directories, persistent disks will also be used for other items like job data (JARs, auxiliary data distributed with the application, etc), but those could just as easily use the boot PD.

Bigger persistent disks are almost always better due to the way GCE scales IOPS and throughput with disk size [1]. 500G is probably a good starting point to start profiling your applications and uses. If you don't use HDFS, find that your applications don't log much, and don't spill to disk when shuffling, then a smaller disk can probably work well.

If you find that you actually don't want or need any persistent disk, then bdutil [2] also exists as a command line script that can create clusters with more configurability and customizability.

1. https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/compute-engine-disks-price-performance-and-persistence/
2. https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/